# Is function component that uses React-hook can be render inside from a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I use react-hook in my all component. Now when I want to render It's inside React_Router BrowserRouter component It's given me an error.

Error Massage: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: You should show the relevant code where you get the error

Comment: thanks for try to help me. My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, I think you could do nested routes with hoo like it.

Here would be your main router for example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";


class Main extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='main'>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/test' component={MyComponent} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

And Here would be your routed component with nested route.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class MyComponent extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        const {path} = this.props.match;
        return (
            <div className='test'>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={`${path}/catalog`}>
                        <div>Route catalog</div>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path={path}>
                        <div>Route dashboard</div>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the past days. In my case the problem was that i use render prop of Route component instead of component prop

```
<Route render={FunCompWithHooks} /> {/* wrong */}
<Route component={FunCompWithHooks} /> {/* correct */}
```